# Dynamic variable name with dashes in thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf, variable-names

I am trying to create a variable name in thymeleaf by using another variable as prefix:

```
th:with="appOverview = ${__${tabId}__AppOverview}"
```

It works most of the times, but in the case where **tabId** contains dashes (i.e., "my-test-tab"), thymeleaf throws the following exception:

> The operator 'SUBTRACT' is not supported between objects of type 'null' and 'null'

I guess that the dashes confuse thymeleaf into believing it's an arithmetic operation between non-existing variables.

I tested adding a variable with *th:with="my-var='bad dashes'"* and it worked fine, so I suppose dashes are generally accepted as characters in variable names.

Is there a way to tackle this issue?

Comment: Thymeleaf is thinking that "-" is minus, not dash and it try subtract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I finally found it!

The thing I was missing is that all model variables are stored in thymeleaf in the #vars object, so accessing them from there won't confuse thymeleaf. Here's what worked:

```
th:with="appOverview = ${#vars.get('__${tabId}__AppOverview')}"
```